# How local variable or function parameters retaining previous values using recursion in below code?

Tags: java, recursion, memory, methods, stack

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str = "Test";
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        pastValues(str, 0, "", res);
        //System.out.println("Ans:::"+res);
    }
    
    public static void pastValues(String str, int index, String curr, List<String> ans){
        
        if(index == str.length()){
            return;
        }
        pastValues(str, index + 1, curr + str.charAt(index), ans);
        System.out.println("Before:::"+ans);
        ans.add(curr + str.charAt(index));
        System.out.println("After:::"+ans);
    }
```

Output is

```
    Before:::[] 
    
    After:::[Test] 
    
    Before:::[Test]
    
    After:::[Test, Tes]
    
    Before:::[Test, Tes]
    
    After:::[Test, Tes, Te]
    
    Before:::[Test, Tes, Te]
    
    After:::[Test, Tes, Te, T]
```

Now my question is how this List **ans** is preserving old values. As per my knowledge, when a method is recursive, it'll create new instances of parameters and their preserved values will vanish when the method returns unless we are returning their values. In this case, I am returning nothing. Then how is it preserving old values too?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Java uses always call-by-value. The argument `ans` is *not* a list, but a reference to the list instance (like `str` is not a String, but a reference to the string instance). This means that you always modify the same list instance.

Comment: @tquadrat Au contraire! [Java is always _pass-by-value_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). The confusion often arises because the _value_ is a _reference_ to the object (with the exception of primitive types).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose – Seen and corrected already … but thank you for notifying!

Comment: "[...] when a method is recursive, it'll create new instances [...]". No, a method (or a method call) never creates instances of whatever by itself, regardless whether it is recursivcely called or not. Only you do!

Answer (score 2):

That is because the variable `ans` is a reference to a list. When you a new element to the list and make a recursive call, the reference is part of the stack and not the actual object (`List<String>`). You are hence modifying the actual object on the heap.

This is same as passing the `List<String>` to a method and adding a new element into the list in the method. When the method call returns back to the caller, changes made in the list will be visible to the caller.